# How do I process responses from using the official Chargify gem in Rails 3.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, chargify

I'm currently developing a Rails application to accept recurring billing using Chargify. I've installed [their gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/chargify_api_ares/0.3.9/frames) and managed to connect to Chargify with the gem. However, some subscriptions go through and some do not.

**My question is how do I handle or even process the response once the gem communicates with the server?**

I don't see anything in the development logs that gives me any indication of a successful data transfer or a failed one. The gem documentation also does not mention anything regarding this.

Thanks for looking.

**UPDATE**

The code I'm playing around with is in my checkout controller:

def checkout
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])

```
Chargify::Customer.create(
  :first_name   => "Charlie",
  :last_name    => "Bull",
  :email        => "charlie@example.com",
  :organization => "Chargify"
)

Chargify::Subscription.create(
  :product_handle => 'recurring',
  :customer_attriburtes => {
    :first_name => @customer.shipping_first_name, 
    :last_name => @customer.shipping_last_name, 
    :email => @customer.email
  },
  :payment_profile_attributes => {
    :first_name => @customer.shipping_first_name,
    :last_name => @customer.shipping_last_name,
    :full_number => "1",
    :expiration_month => 1,
    :expiration_year => 2012,
    :billing_address => @customer.shipping_street_address,
    :billing_city => @customer.shipping_city,
    :billing_state => @customer.shipping_state,
    :billing_zip => @customer.shipping_zip_code,
    :billing_country => @customer.shipping_country
  }
)

#if @subscription.save
#  logger.info "saved description"
#  redirect_to process_path
#else
#  redirect_to :back, :alert =>"There was an error."
#end
```

end

The customer create is going through, but the Subscription does not. I'm just looking for a callback from the server so I can act based off whether it succeeded and find out why the subscription isn't going through.

Comment: It looks like the code checks the response code for a few requests and if it gets an unexpected response it raises an UnexpectedResponseError. Can you give us some example code?

Comment: Put my controller code up. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this whole gem uses ActiveResource cant you just call something like:

```
# Create a subscription from a customer reference
subscription = Chargify::Subscription.create(
  :customer_reference => 'moklett',
  :product_handle => 'chargify-api-ares-test',
  :credit_card_attributes => {
    :first_name => "Michael",
    :last_name => "Klett",
    :expiration_month => 1,
    :expiration_year => 2020,
    :full_number => "1"
  }
)
if subscription.save
  puts "Created Subscription!"
else
  puts "Subscription Failed!"
end
```

and see if the record has been created correctly?

EDIT: Your code should work but I see that the call to save is commented out. When you call `save` it creates or updates the record and testing this should allow you to determine if your record was created or not.

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying, but the official Chargify API is here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/chargify_api_ares/0.3.9/frames

Comment: Try using the code above. Also im not sure why your save call is commented out or where you define @subscription.

Comment: Yep, I was on the right track, but what I was missing was getting the error messages which I eventually found I could get by calling: `messages = ''
      subscription.errors.full_messages.each {|error| messages += error + "<br />"}
      logger.info messages`